# Using Unix sockets with socket2

Tags: rust, unix-socket

I'm trying to build a Unix-domain socket using the [socket2](https://crates.io/crates/socket2) crate and the most basic code fails to compile:

```
extern crate socket2;
use socket2::*;

fn main() {
    let socket = Socket::new(Domain::unix(), Type::dgram(), None).unwrap();
}
```

This is the error:

> ```
> 5 | let socket = Socket::new(Domain::unix(), Type::dgram(), None).unwrap();
>   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in 
>                                                `socket2::Domain`
> ```

The [documentation](https://docs.rs/socket2/0.3.7/socket2/struct.Domain.html) indicates, that unix function is "only available on Unix when the unix feature is activated". I'm running this code on a Ubuntu machine. Do I need to activate anything else in my cargo file for this function to be enabled? The crate lacks examples that I can rely on.

Comment: This is not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please try to create one

Comment: Code has been edited.

Comment: Why don't you just use a regular [UDP socket](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html)?

Comment: The use I have is for IPC between processes that require to communicate using socket files for various other reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [This function is only available on Unix when the `unix` feature is activated.](https://docs.rs/socket2/0.3.7/socket2/struct.Domain.html#method.unix)

And [How to activate a feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#choosing-features)

In your case just add this to your cargo manifest:

```
[dependencies.socket2]
version = "0.3.7"
features = ["unix"]
```